# Standalone Java Unit Test v/s Tomcat web app

Tags: java, performance, tomcat8

We are testing the load on a web app, using jmeter. Now, with Jmeter, the server just gives up after some time, around 100 DB connections. The issue is that the standalone java unit test runs for more than 2000 invocations without any slow up or blocking and I see that a single DB connection is used for it. Why is there such a huge difference in the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, standalone unit tests won't be inside a transaction and in the tomcat webapp almost everything is a transaction and hence the DB connections are open for a longer time.

Answer (score 0):

The tests that I ran were direct connections to DB and kind of single DB calls, but whereas in tomcat, the workflows are longer and more random. With these points in mind, I have started modifying the tomcat web app code to minimize these transactions and use read-only queries wherever needed.